# Magic Item Compendium, Confusion About "+1 Bonus" Price

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I've just been skimming through the Magic Item Compendium & I'm confused about the "+*n* Bonus" prices on some of the items, does this mean that a player using the item is subject to a penalty?

For example:

> RETALIATION Price: +2 bonus Property: Armor Caster Level: 9th Aura:
>   Moderate; (DC 19) necromancy Activation: — The surface of this armor
>   roils with pent-up energy. A suit of armor that has this property
>   strikes back at foes who hit hard in melee...

Reading more, the MIC p.4 explains pricing as below:

> Price (Item Level): The purchase price of the item, in gold pieces
>   (gp). The item’s level (see page 226) is given in parentheses

Which sounds to me like there is a set price for bonuses and the item/property is equivalent to that, however I've not managed to find any mention of a structure like that.

Looking through Chapter 6: "Using Magical Items", there are lots of mentions of bonuses but nothing I can see that could be construed as being applicable as a pricing structure.

I think I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When determining the price or a magic weapon or armor you look at the bonus it provides plus any increases from properties. So assuming that the Retaliation property was placed on a +1 suit of armor it would be costed as though it were a +3 suit of armor (9000gp + the cost of the masterwork suit of armor)

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm) (emphasis added):

> In addition to an enhancement bonus, armor may have special abilities. **Special abilities usually count as additional bonuses for determining the market value of an item, but do not improve AC.** A suit of armor cannot have an effective bonus (enhancement plus special ability bonus equivalents) higher than +10. A suit of armor with a special ability must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.

Comment: Ah, that SRD link is very helpful, thanks. I must admit I'm still a bit confused with all this table referencing.

So if I wanted to apply the *Resistance* property to a bog-standard set of Leather armour.

Leather armour is 10gp, to which the 150gp cost is added for *masterwork* quality, seeing as magic items are inherently masterwork. That is in line with the cost shown in the "Random Armour Type" table.

The "+1 Bonus" is then the level you apply from the "Item" column of the "Armour and Shields" table, which gives you the price.

Which would be **1,160gp**

Is that correct?

Comment: @N00b-a-Tron9000 Don't forget that the armor must be at least +1 to have other properties added to it (last sentence of the rule I quoted in my answer), but otherwise it looks like you are doing it right.

Comment: @noob-a-tron 9000 also before you can make armor a +1 it must first be MW. So (base value + MW + "+1" +other enchantments) .....also  not to get too complicated but there are also additional costs for applying properties to a non-standard slot (ie boots of darkvision) or adding/mixing different enchantments..